# Plot grouped data using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

Hi I have a table like this:

```
Question Age_Group Value
Question 1 10-20 15
Question 2 10-20 16
Question 3 10-20 12
.....
Question 1 20-30 13
Question 2 20-30 15
Question 3 20-30 18
```

I want to build a histogram where questions are in y - axis, age groups in x - axis and by bars the comparision is visible based on Value column.

How to make this possible?
Regards

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example with your code? Check this thread and the `dput` option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi @Arault. Actually I cannot provide ggplot code for this plot because that is what I am thinking about

Comment: Could you add the dput output of your dataset then? So we can try with your data without having to manually copy the dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Do you want facets? E.g. something like this:

```r
set.seed(123)
DF <- data.frame(Question = rep(paste0("Question ", 1:10), 80),
  Age_Group = factor(sample(c("10-20", "20-30", "30-40", "40-50"), 
    800, replace=TRUE)),
  Value = sample(8:30, 800, replace = TRUE))
DF$Question <- factor(DF$Question, unique(DF$Question))

library(ggplot2)  
ggplot(DF, aes(x=Value)) + 
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_grid(Question ~ Age_Group) +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0))
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>